# Computer simulation of a battle of the Crusades. In perhaps the first cyberpunk anthology

Tags: story-identification, virtual-worlds, cyberpunk

I'm looking for a short story that describes a battle of the Crusades. After the description of the battle (perhaps Battle of Ascalon? Crusaders on the march defeat an Islamic army in the open?) it is revealed the battle is a computer recreation.

I read this in a cyberpunk anthology, back in the 1980's or early '90s. no later then 1992. This was the first description of the sort of computer simulation or virtual reality I had ever read, and the collection contained the first cyberpunk stories I was ever exposed to. I'm not sure that term was in use at the time these stories were written. I can't be sure of the other stories in the collection, and don't want to muddy the waters with inaccurate recollection.

Sorry there is so little to go on.